# Protocol vs Subclass

Tags: swift, protocols, subclass

I want to create a protocol `Pannable` so I can add it to my existing cells so I can pan them:

```
@objc protocol Pannable {
    var panGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer { get }

    var margin: CGPoint { get }

    var limitLeft: CGFloat { get set }
    var limitRight: CGFloat { get set }

    var shadowOn: Bool { get set }

    var background: UIView { get set }
    var shadowView: UIView { get set }

    var enablePanR: Bool { get set }
    var enablePanL: Bool { get set }

    func handlePan(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer)
}

extension Pannable where Self: UITableViewCell {

    var original: CGFloat { return background.frame.minX }

    func handlePan(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        // pan cell
    }

    func configureLayout() {
        contentView.layer.cornerRadius = background.layer.cornerRadius
        let size = shadowOn ? shadowView.layer.shadowOffset.height : 0

        let height = bounds.height - margin.y - size
        let widths = bounds.width - margin.x * 2

        let rect = CGRect(x: margin.x, y: size, width: widths, height: height)

        background.frame = rect
        contentView.frame = rect

        shadowView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: background.layer.cornerRadius).cgPath
    }

    func setup() {
        insertSubview(background, at: 0)
        insertSubview(shadowView, at: 0)

        background.clipsToBounds = true

        panGesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handlePan))
        panGesture.delegate = self

        addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
    }

    func reset() {
        contentView.frame.origin.x = original
    }

    func enableShadow() {
        shadowView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2, height: 2)
        shadowView.layer.shadowRadius = 2
        shadowView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        shadowView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

        shadowOn = true
    }
}
```

To use this `Pannable` I'll have to add `setup()` and `configureLayout()` to the cell's initializer and `layoutSubviews()`:

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    setup()
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    configureLayout()
}
```

But that means I might just as well subclass `UITableViewCell` and add it directly instead of creating a protocol. Is there a way to use a protocol and extend a `UITableViewCell` conforming the protocol with the proper initializer / layoutSubviews?

Answer (score 1):

Your problems run deeper than the question suggests. Surely you've noticed (from the screams of the compiler) that this isn't going to work:

```
extension Pannable where Self: UITableViewCell {
    func handlePan(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        // pan cell
    }
    func setup() {
        panGesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handlePan))
    }
}
```

A protocol extension is a Swift feature. Objective-C can't see it. But a selector is an Objective-C feature. So it cannot see a function declared in a Swift protocol extension.

Basically, trying to use a protocol extension to inject functionality into an Objective-C class that Objective-C itself will automatically call in some way is a doomed project. For exactly that reason, a subclass is going to make a lot more sense here.